# Grouping Categories

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, subquery, categories

I am trying to group each category and count the total number of cities in each category.

The results should look like this

```
+------------------------------+--------------+

| GNPPopRatioCategory | CountRecords |

+------------------------------+--------------+

| 1. Equal or greater than 2% | 145 |

| 2. Equal or greater than 1% | 104 |

| 3. Equal or greater than .5% | 566 |

| 4. Rest of country | 3264 |
```

This is what I have so far however I cannot figure out how to group them and count the cities in each category.  I have been informed that using an Inline view is more efficient however I would like to figure out this way first before I moved on to Inline Views.  Thanks for the help.

```
Select Count(Country.GNP / City.Population) AS CountRecords,
(Select Case When CountRecords>= 2 THEN "1.Equal or greater than 2%"
When CountRecords>= 1 THEN "1.Equal or greater than 1%"
When CountRecords>= .5 THEN "1.Equal or greater than .5%"
ELSE "Rest of country" END) AS GNPPopRatioCategory
From City INNER JOIN Country ON City.Country=Country.Code 
Limit 20;
```

City table described: ID, name, Country, District, Population
Country Table described: Code, Name, Continent, Region, SurfaceArea, IndepYear, Population, LifeExpectancy, GNP, LocalName, GovernmentForm, HeadOfState, Capital

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is structured in an unusual and incorrect way.  You have a subquery with no `from`.

I think you want to take the rate of the GNP and Population and place that in categories, and then count the numbers in each category.  This following query takes this approach:

```
Select Count(*) AS CountRecords,
       (Case When Country.GNP / City.Population >= 2 THEN "1.Equal or greater than 2%"
             When Country.GNP / City.Population >= 1 THEN "1.Equal or greater than 1%"
             When Country.GNP / City.Population >= .5 THEN "1.Equal or greater than .5%"
             ELSE "Rest of country"
        END) AS GNPPopRatioCategory
From City INNER JOIN
     Country
     ON City.Country = Country.Code 
group by (Case When Country.GNP / City.Population>= 2 THEN "1.Equal or greater than 2%"
               When Country.GNP / City.Population>= 1 THEN "1.Equal or greater than 1%"
               When Country.GNP / City.Population>= .5 THEN "1.Equal or greater than .5%"
               ELSE "Rest of country"
        END)
Limit 20;
```

Normally when you do a `limit` you want to have an `order by`.  In this case, there are only four categories, so the limit is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you very much and I will be studying this query and what you have said so that I know to do the right query in the future.  Thanks for you knowledge regards

Comment: @user2380034 . . . Glad I could help.  I noticed that the strings in the query match those in your query, but they all start with "1".  You need to change them both in the `select` and in the `group by` clauses.

Comment: Thanks again I just noticed myself.  Regards,